# Tracking number of function calls + closures (à la SICP) in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming, scheme, closures

This is a question about **scope** and **closures** in **Python**, motivated by an exercise in SICP. Much thanks for your time if you read this!

A question (3.2) in SICP asks one to create a procedure "make-monitored", that takes in a function f (of one parameter) as input and returns a procedure that keeps track of how many times f has been called. (If the input to this new procedure is "num-calls" it returns the number of times f has been called, if it is "reset" it resets counter to 0 and anything else, it applies f to the input and returns the result (after appropriately incrementing the counter).

Here is code in Scheme that I wrote that works:

```
(define (make-monitored f)
  (let ((counter 0))
     (define (number-calls) counter)
     (define (reset-count)
       (set! counter 0))
     (define (call-f input)
       (begin (set! counter (+ 1 counter))
              (f input)))
    (define (dispatch message)
      (cond ((eq? message 'num-calls) (number-calls))
            ((eq? message 'reset) (reset-count))
            (else (call-f message))))
    dispatch))
```

My question however is about **how to write this in a "pythonic" way**. My attempt below is obviously a direct translation of my Scheme code and I realize that though it is fine for an impure functional language (like Scheme) it's probably not the cleanest or best way to do it in Python. How does one solve a general problem like this in Python where you want a higher order procedure to dispatch on type and remember local state?

Below is my noobish attempt that works (earlier I had said it did not but the problem was that an earlier version of the program was still in the terminal's memory) (In 2 it seems hard to make nonlocal variable binding)

```
def make_monitored(func):
    counter = 0                      
    def dispatch(message):
        if message == "num-calls":
            return num_calls()
        elif message == "reset":
            reset()
        else:
            nonlocal counter
            counter += 1
            return func(message)
    def num_calls():
        nonlocal counter
        return counter
    def reset():
        nonlocal counter
        counter = 0
    return dispatch
```

PS: This question is related to [this same set of exercises in SICP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591403/sicp-section-3-1-1-local-state-in-procedures-seems-inconsistent) but my question is really about Python best practice and not the concept of closures or Scheme...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think writing a decorator wrapping the function in a class would be more pythonic:

```
from functools import wraps 

def make_monitored(func):
    class wrapper:
        def __init__(self, f):
            self.func = f
            self.counter = 0
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.counter += 1
            return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wraps(func)(wrapper(func))
```

This has the advantage that it mimics the original function as close as possible, and just adds a `counter` field to it:

```
In [25]: msqrt = make_monitored(math.sqrt)
In [26]: msqrt(2)
Out[26]: 1.4142135623730951
In [29]: msqrt.counter
Out[29]: 1
In [30]: msqrt(235)
Out[30]: 15.329709716755891
In [31]: msqrt.counter
Out[31]: 2
In [32]: @make_monitored
    ...: def f(a):
    ...:     """Adding the answer"""
    ...:     return a + 42
In [33]: f(0)
Out[33]: 42
In [34]: f(1)
Out[34]: 43
In [35]: f.counter
Out[35]: 2
In [36]: f.__name__
Out[36]: 'f'
In [37]: f.__doc__
Out[37]: 'Adding the answer'
```

For `f`, you also see the usage as a decorator, and how the wrapper keeps the original name and docstring (which would not be the case without `functools.wraps`).

Defining `reset` is left as an exercise to the reader, but quite trivial.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!